# Atomic writes to multiple locations in file?

Tags: c, linux, file

I have a database in C that I need to do atomic updates on. Specifically, it's a file stored like this

```
header: MAX_USERS/8 bytes
users: MAX_USERS*sizeof(USER) bytes
```

The file is [truncated](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate) because it's really sparse and has a high capacity.

When the database is opened, I read the whole header into memory, but none of the users.

When a request comes in to create a user, I'd like to do this:

```
// modify header in memory
// initialize user
// atomically: write header and user to disk
```

The only flags I can find for file I/O pertaining to this are O_SYNC and O_DSYNC, but they do the opposite of what I want, forcing `fwrite` calls to be atomic. What I really want is something like this:

```
// somehow, make file only write to disk when fflush is called
// write header to disk (fseek/fwrite)
// write user to disk (fseek/fwrite)
// if both of those succeeded: fflush/fsync
```

I am wondering if this can be done by explicitly providing a user-space buffer for the file via something like `setvbuf` with `_IOFBF`, but I don't know if that would work.

Comment: I think I'd use `write(2)` [et. al.] instead of `fwrite`

Comment: File read/write operations on arbitrary file ranges are not atomic, and fundamentally *cannot be* atomic. What *can* be atomic is `rename()`, so you *could* make a private copy of the file, edit it, and `rename()` the copy to the original file. However, AFAIK POSIX doesn't provide a way to ensure that nobody else has `renamed()` the file in the interim (conceptually you *could* have a rename that took an additional filedescriptor for the target, and failed if it didn't correspond to the file currently named by the filename), so you need locking anyway.

Comment: @EOF Wouldn't that require me copying the entire file? I'd only like to modify a few bytes.

Comment: Managing file writes is *hard*. Just ask the PostgreSQL developers about `fsync()`.

Comment: @EOF Just read https://lwn.net/Articles/752063/, yikes

Comment: Yes, it's a mess. Basically cheap hardware + horrible legacy APIs like POSIX + "fun" requirements like hot-pluggable USB = managing persistence is a nightmare.

Comment: If you want "atomic" anything then you need to step away from anything that's buffered, which is what `fwrite` and `FILE*` are all about. Use low-level calls, and as EOF points out, pick the least-crappy-and-broken solution to achieve what you need. You'd think writing files to disk would be easy, but with how many types of filesystems there are, from ZFS to NFS to SMB and so on, the answer is always "it's complicated".

Comment: As mentioned, there is no way to atomically write a file.  The usual solution here is to lock the file while you are updating it - Unix provides several different mechanisms for file locking with varying semantics.

Comment: @tadman: That doesn't really help as the low level calls aren't atomic either.

Comment: @Landstalker To clarify, `write[v]()` *is* atomic with respect to other processes reading or writing to the file (though not necessarily with regard to the disk access), but only for a single (consecutive/sequential) write operation.

Comment: @NateEldredge Agreed, but if you're using `fwrite` you're already several levels away from getting there.

Comment: @EOF The problem is when writing to arbitrary locations, `lseek()` + `write()` is not atomic.  [The solution is to use `pwrite()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html) - which **is** atomic.  Note that while each `[p]write()` operation is atomic, partial operations can occur: "If `write()` is interrupted by a signal after it successfully writes some data, it shall return the number of bytes written."

Comment: @AndrewHenle The way I understand this question, it would require atomically wiring to *multiple separate ranges* in the file. That's not atomic with `write()`, nor `pwrite()`, nor `writev()`, nor `pwritev()`.

Comment: I wonder: If you `mmap()` the file, and then use hardware transactional memory (available on modern POWER and broken on some Intel x86), you probably could make the modification appear atomic.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html might give some insight into ways to approach the problem.

Comment: See also: https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html